# removing ad-hoc polymorphism

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

What is the best way to remove ad-hoc polymorshism in haskell ?

80% of the time, I don't need `fmap` to be polymorphic in `Functor f`, I actually know which instance I apply it to. Replacing it with a specific instance gives me :

- less brain inference when reading code, more brain checking
- more type error caught when type checker verifies

What is the best way to apply, like in category theory, a functor F to a morphism in haskell using its name ?

```
-- F is a functor : it maps objects of * to objects of *
data F r = Z | Suc r

-- F is a functor : it maps arrows of *  to arrows of *
-- generic fmap will be found for this type, I inherit much code for free, great
instance Functor F where
  fmap f Z       = Z
  fmap f (Suc n) = Suc (f n)

-- But I care writing code specific for this functor only
-- Applies F for arrows of *
fmapF = fmap :: (a -> b) -> (F a -> F b)

-- an arrow in *, aka a function -- (and also a value as * is CCC)
f = id :: a -> a

-- works for values F a, not any functor f
r = fmapF f Z :: F a
r' = fmap f "hi" -- as opposed to
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: if you're exposing `fmapF` to users (or colleagues), you're giving them something that's more difficult to reason about from the type (`fmapF` can do infinitely more possible things, and I don't know what properties it has).

Comment: @jberryman Actually, it can't do infinitely more things -- the typeclass constraint has already weakened parametricity.

Comment: @chi how so ? from the point of view of the user, isn't it just a normal function, there are no typeclass constraint. fmapF can just give back Z, which fmap can not

Comment: @jberryman actually what would be nice would be to play with that specific F, then explicitely quantify, to have best of both world. It should be possible with Dict I suppose, to have (named) instances enter the context. like fix does, or ST, but at type level

Comment: @nicolas Sure, but the functor instance can also do anything `fmapF` can. It would be "wrong" to write a law-breaking instance, but types do not prevent that.

Comment: @chi The distinction is interesting. "theorems for free" restrictions come from  parametric polymorphism which will always be true without boundaries. fmap give you guarantee that *it* will do lawful operations within its own boundaries

Comment: @nicolas I'm unsure about what you are implying. There are, exactly, the same parametricity guarantees for a standalone `fmapF` and the instance `fmap` definition. Both have the same polytype, and are subject to the same free theorem. A definition `fmap _ _ = Z` is allowed by parametricity, and it breaks the functor laws -- just as one can do using a standalone `fmapF` definition. So your "lawful operations" does not imply the functor laws.

Comment: fmap ensure some laws, _provided_ a lawful implementation of Functor. that's quite something. fmapF does not ensure anything. It boils down to the same in the "end" as we have to resolve things statically, but you could imagine having mutiple stages of resolution. the (polymorphic) parametricity guarantee are just the one that are valid across every stages, they are context free (thus context-laws free). as I understand things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you actually want

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
r = fmap @ F f Z
```

The `@ F` part specifies that we want the `fmap` of functor `F`.

Comment: YES ! that's nice. Now we have names... bindings.. slippery slope. I guess you can nest `Dict t` to play with that :)